# libLAS las2las scrubs ground point data on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, lidar, liblas

I am trying to use las2las from libLAS on Ubuntu 14.04 entering the following code into the terminal:

```
las2las --input merged.las --output ground.las --keep-class 2
```

This outputs a LAS file which has bounds -214.XX, -214.XX,-214.XX,-214.XX. Just to make sure the merged.las file was good, I was able to open it up and view it in ArcGIS 10.2.2 on a Windows 7 machine. I've also tried a variant where --input was changed to -i and likewise for --output, but got similar results.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? Is there something wrong in my code?

**EDIT:
After more testing, I found out my real issue is lasmerge. I have tried the following two lines of code**

```
ls *.las > lidardata.txt
lasmerge -i lidardata.txt -o indianhill.las
```

I have also tried:

```
lasmerge -i 640.las -i 641.las -i 686.las -i 687.las -o indiantwo.las
```

Both of them result in incorrect bounds. I have also tried the -verbose flag, which the help/manual suggest lasmerge should have. But, I get an error saying that it is *not* a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have a typo inside your code. Instead of `class`, it should be `classes`. See [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/las2las.1.html#contenttoc4) (manpages.ubuntu.com).

Try this:

```
las2las --input merged.las --output ground.las --keep-classes 2
```

Comment: Andre, I have upvoted you because you did correctly answer the question. However, I have updated my question noting that the issue that I have is apparently due to lasmerge and not las2las. Do you happen to have any ideas what the issue with lasmerge might be?